# dbDelta/SQL error, very unexpected

Tags: sql, wordpress

Here's an error that I'm having trouble with. It occurs when I use the dbDelta function in Wordpress. I can't really figure it out, perhaps someone else has experience something similar? My code:

```
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE `".$table_name1."` (
`id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT  PRIMARY KEY ,
`blogid` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
`symbol` VARCHAR( 255 ) NOT NULL
) ENGINE = MYISAM";
```

I trigger this code during the theme_switch action. And it does not seem to occur when I turn the theme on, only when I switch to something else (I know, it's weird). I have read and I have attempted to follow the caveats mentioned at [Wordpress.org](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins), for example putting two spaces between primary key and the definition. I have two other, similar, pieces of SQL code that generate the same error; all three were originally generated by phpMyAdmin so I know that they work.

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-experiment/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 1463

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-experiment/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 1463

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-experiment/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php on line 1463

WordPress database error: [Multiple primary key defined]
ALTER TABLE wp_stocks_0 CHANGE COLUMN id `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-experiment/wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php:1463) in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/wp-experiment/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 897
```

In case I have misunderstood dbDelta, I should perhaps add, that the above code is executed several times.. so the table already exists. But if I understand dbDelta, that means it simply ought to do nothing because there is nothing in the db structure that needs changing.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try --

```
$sql1 = "CREATE TABLE `".$table_name1."` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`blogid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`symbol` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM";
```

In my experience, `dbDelta` is even fussier than alluded to in the Codex.

**Update**
From your edit, I would suggest you first check / only create the database if it doesn't exist yet, which you can do using --

```
global $wpdb;

if ($wpdb->get_var("show tables like `" . $wpdb->prefix . $table_name1 . "`") != $wpdb->prefix . $table_name1) {
  // your dbDelta query here
}
```

Comment: It didn't work, but it changed the error message to 
ALTER TABLE wp_stocks_0 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`) :/

Comment: If you use the if statement noted here then future changes to the table structure will not be implemented.   Unless you are 100% certain you will never modify the table structure in the future I would avoid this construct.

Answer (score 7):

A bit late - but discovered this question when searching for a solution to the same error messages - I'm adding an answer for anyone else who discovers this:

from the codex docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins

> - You must not use any apostrophes or backticks around field names.

That fixed it for me

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had an extra space between 'create table' and the table name.

I had:

```
$sqlOptions = "CREATE TABLE  $options_table_name (
```

Where I needed:

```
$sqlOptions = "CREATE TABLE $options_table_name (
```

Picky function

Comment: I was missing the space after my table name. Very picky indeed.